# Delete first element in database SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql

How to delete the first element in the table of a database ?

this my table structure

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `etudiant` (
  `cin` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `nom` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `prenom` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `datenaissance` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `adresse` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `mail` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `tel` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`cin`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

and im working with wampserver on phpmyadmin

Comment: What's your database structure? What have you tried? MS SQL? Oracle? MySQL? You need to provide more info.

Comment: What database are you using? MySQL? PostgreSQL? SQL Server? Have you read any of their ample documentation?

Answer (score 1):

Was it a syntax error?

```
delete from etudiant where cin = (select cin from etudiant order by cin limit 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no such thing as the first row in a table.  However, if the ordering is specified by a column (such as a date or the primary key or something), you can use `LIMIT`:

```
delete e from etudiant
    order by cin
    limit 1;
```

If you want to delete an *indeterminate* row, you can remove the `order by`.

Comment: it dosen't delete the first one

Comment: @KilaniJradKarim . . . Did you read the answer?  There is no *first* record in a table.  It is an unordered set.  You need some column, such as an auto-incremented id or creation date or something else to specify the ordering.